# repeated random generator, how to store and use the first value generated

Tags: java

A game i am messing about with calls a set of code many times a minute to check for conditions. Within this code i have random generators that generate a new number every time the game checks the conditions, this is fine for most purposes, but for one random number i want to keep the first value generated for use and discard the rest. Is there a way to do this please?

```
 int l = random.nextInt(1000);
                    int k1 = l - 500;
                    l = random.nextInt(1000);
                    int j2 = l - 500;
                    int i3 = random.nextInt(500);
                    int l3 = i3 - 250;
                    int k4 = random.nextInt(500);
                    int l4 = k4 - 250;
                    int i5 = random.nextInt(100);
                    int j5 = random.nextInt(100);                    

                    if(j5 < 50)
                       {
                            if(i5 > 0 && i5 <= 7)
                            {  

                            } else
                            if(i5 > 7 && i5 <= 16) 
                            {

                            }else
                            if(i5 > 16 && i5 <= 21)
                            { 

                            }                          

                    if(j5 > 49)
                            if(i5 > 0 && i5 <= 3)
                            {

                             } else
                            if(i5 > 3 && i5 <= 6)
                            {

                            } else
                            if(i5 > 6 && i5 <= 9)
```

Above is a reduced version of part of my code, the random int i am interested in is **j5** which controls all the if else statements. Basically as it is now the game checks the code x times a minute so **j5** can take any value and therefore i get instances of both **if else** statements occurring ( the routine above is set to run for 20 turns, but the game checks the whole code x times a minute, so setting up a random integer outside this code has the same problem of the number being regenerated x times a minute).

What i want to do is the first time this code runs is the value of **j5** to be stored and used for the remaining turns ( don't take much notice of the **j < 50** and **j > 49** values, they are just test values to make sure the basic code is working ok)

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Have you considered storing it into a variable?

Comment: Could you expand please? My java skills are quite limited. I did try declaring it inside a separate if statement along with a counter, but i had compile errors for variable not found.  Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class A{
private Integer j5;
    public A(){
        j5 = null;
    }

    public void checkingMethode(){
        //Generate a bunch of randoms
        if (j5 == null) {
            j5 = random.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
}
```

This way j5 will only be assigned a value once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will try your suggestion and the one above and let you know how i get on.                                                                       regards

Comment: Tried this but cannot get it to compile without errors, where exactly would i insert it into my code?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting errors?
Class A was an example, I suppose you're working in a class which has some kind of constructor. Initialise j5 as null in this constructor and than in your methode which does the checking you linked above you check if j5 is null, which means it hasn't ever been assigned a value yet. If this is the case you assign it a random value. I also modified my original answer as it had some uncompileable code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this code is inside a class method which is called.
You could use a static int class variable, in the same class.

```
private static int j5;
```

then use

```
if (null==this.j5) this.j5=random.nextInt(100);
```

so first time the code is run, it is set and stays set.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion and help, i will try it out later and let you know how i get on. You are correct it is inside a class method.

Comment: Just had time to try this suggestion out, but when i try and compile i get an error message     operator == cannot be applied to <null>,int    any suggestion please?